# Images in bootstrap5 not loading

Tags: html, image, bootstrap-5

I am making a website and using html in vsc with bootstrap5, but the images I have put in a new section are not loading and idk why if the ones I put in previous sections can be seen perfectly.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center my-1 mt-5">Portafolio</h2>
  <p class="text-center mb-4">Subtítulo</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="/img/recursos/foto1.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen 1">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Título de la imagen 1</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Descripción de la imagen 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to check if there were any syntax errors or if the image wasn't located there but I haven't been able to find the mistake. I only need the image to be visible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yours,

```
<img src="/img/recursos/foto1.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen 1">
```

Modified,

```
 <img src="./img/recursos/foto1.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen 1">
```

In front of the path put a ".", to know you are in the current directory.